# Install an external library instance of libv8-3.14 to folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, v8

I need `libv8-3.14` to run some R packages on linux, but I don't have root access/sudo access on the linux computer I'm using so I'd like to install an external folder instance of `libv8-3.14`. I've seen R packages reference this as external as `CDFLAG="folder/v8-3.14"` so I know it is possible.

I'm new(ish) to linux but I've installed external libraries before with tar.gz files which then have a configure file in them, which I set the external folder with `./configure --prefix==/folder/loc`, but the only downloads I can find of libv8 are .git (which I can't get to work either).

How can I install an libv8-3.14 to a folder and install so I can set: 
`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/install/`

and

```
export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/install/`
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. In case somebody in the future comes across this post, I will leave my suggestions and how it worked out in the end. Also, all credits go to an experienced colleague of mine.

The most sure thing to do is to consult IT, or someone who has already had the same problem, there is usually a workaround these issues.

A way you can do it yourself:

- Create an anaconda environment, you can name it 'V8' or something (make sure the environment is based on the latest python version, or recent enough for r-v8).
- activate it
- install the [conda version of the V8 R interface](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-v8) with `conda install -c conda-forge r-v8`

That's it. Whenever you need V8, fire up your environment beforehand, and it should be A-OK.

Further advice: If you run into errors when installing r-v8, it may be a good idea to update your conda and all the packages. However, depending on your conda version `conda update conda` and `conda upgrade --all` MAY BREAK your conda installation, so be careful. (For further information on this problem, see the endless complaints of people in this issue: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8920).

Answer (score 0):

V8 doesn't use autotools, so it has no `./configure`. In fact, it provides no installation facilities at all, because it is meant for embedding, not installing.

What I would try is to download the Ubuntu package (guessing from your other question, you are on Ubuntu, right?) for the right architecture from https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libv8-3.14.5, and extracting it manually. `.deb` files are just ZIP archives.

As a side note, there's no point in setting `PATH`, because libv8, being a library, provides no executables. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is all you need.

Comment: I do that but I get a folder called "debian" that has some install files in it `changelog   control.in.in    libv8-dev.examples  rules        watch.in
compat      copyright        libv8-dev.install   samples.gyp
control     copyright_hints  patches             source
control.in  gbp.conf         README.source       watch`, what do I do with these to get a lib folder?

Comment: I don't know what you downloaded but this is the list of files you should be getting after extracting: https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libv8-3.14.5/filelist